# Regex for complicated addresses

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a way to extract the street numbers from a string representing a street address. It has to be able to handle multiple numbers as in `"7 & 14 Sample Street"` as well as street numbers with letters as in `"221b Baker street"`, and of course apartments.

E.g.

```
street_address = "123 & 221b Baker Street"
```

returns:

```
street_number = "123 & 221b"
```

And

```
street_address = "123/345 Sample Street"
```

returns:

```
street_number = "123/345"
```

Basically I need am looking for a quick way to extract the street number from an address, even if that address is more complicated than your regular "123 Sample Street" type address.

Is it possible for a regex to find the first space after the last number in a string? And return everything before that space? That seems to be the most straightforward way I can think of.

EDIT:
Thank you for all the help everyone. I think I have managed to work with all addresses:

```
/\w+(\s?\S{1,3}\s)*/
```

Covers addresses with spaces and/or ampersands/slashes/etc…I think

Comment: Your tl;dr comment won't work on:  123 12th St.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex `/\w+(\s\&\s\w+)*/`

```
s = "123 & 221b Baker Street"
s[/\w+(\s\&\s\w+)*/]
# => "123 & 221b" 

s = "7 & 14 Sample Street"
s[/\w+(\s\&\s\w+)*/]
# => "7 & 14"

s = "221b Baker street"
s[/\w+(\s\&\s\w+)*/]
# => "221b"
```

NOTE: You can put a `*` after the `\s`, if the the space between numbers may or may not be present.

Comment: I think the OP needs to give more examples. I doubt that the answer should rely on the presence of `&`

Comment: Yeah Neil is right. Although thank you for the example. The string that needs to be parsed is one that is filled in by a client for Street address, so there is no telling whether they will use & or 'and' or what format they will write their address in. Ideally I would love to go back and reformat the form to have a separate input for street number. But the address is embedded too deep elsewhere to do so.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the & to \S*
Sorry if that won't work. I am new to regex and still trying to work it out

Comment: I modified this code a bit and got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, the question asked for the first space after the last number, which is what is known as a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is a **variable length** lookbehind, which is not supported by most Regex engines, so the best bet is to capture the whole regex for the numbers, and then check the length, like so:

```
s = "123 & 221b Baker Street"
/(^\w+(?:\s\&\s\w+)*)/.match { |m| m[1].try(:length).to_i }
# => 10

s[10..-1]
# => " Baker Street"
```

**Note** I have used `Object#try` in this answer, which is a Rails Core extension.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(.*\d\S*)\s+.*$
```

Street numbers are in group 1.